# How to add 'space' between dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see there is spacing between the Label and Button via HTML, but when dynamically created via JS, there isn't. The CSS in the browser looks the same.

[image: Html vs Js]

It's because the HTML tags are on separate lines, creating a 'space' in between? If I put it on the same line it looks like the JS equivalent.

Now how to reproduce this in JS? A `br` element puts the button physically on a new line which is not what I want.

```js
const label = document.createElement("label");
label.htmlFor = `cash3`;
label.textContent = `Week 3:`
const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
```

```html
<label for="cash1">Week 1:</label>
<button>Del</button>
```

Comment: Why not try putting a space after the colon in your `textContent` ?

Comment: Doesn't work, though it's not like I have a space in the html version? It's because the `button` is on a new line it seems?

Comment: Your code snippet is not runnable, please create a [mcve]

Comment: You can use `&nbsp;` to add a space in `html`.

Comment: The problem is that you are having 2 inline elements. to fully control the layout, you should use [flexbox](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/). Wrap the elements with a wrapper and set `gap: 4px` to make a space between the elements.

Comment: The best way to consistently handle this would be to use CSS for spacing

Comment: The code doesn't demonstrate anything, because you don't append the created elements to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a margin-right property for label tag as common CSS, anyway, we need some margin-right for each label (say 5px right). so that you can avoid changing the JS code it will be inappropriate and you can able to create multiple dynamic from elements.

```
const label = document.createElement("label");
label.htmlFor  = `cash3`;
label.textContent = `Week 3:`
const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
delBtn.textContent = `Del`

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(label);
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(delBtn);
```

CSS:

```
label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
// or
button {
  margin: 0 5px;    // margin on both left & right sides of button 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'You can use `&nbsp;` to add a space in html' -
@Bladimir Medrano Vargas seems to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can style them as you want via js. you should post the complete js code only that creates the element. without posting any HTML. because your js code doesn't create anything.

anyway, I edited the code and added a few things. you can just remove the `br` if you want them in the same line and adjust the `margin` as you want.

```js
var body = document.getElementById("body");

var br = document.createElement("br");
var label = document.createElement("label");
var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
var label2 = document.createElement("label");
var delBtn2 = document.createElement("button");

label.innerHTML = "week 1 :"
delBtn.innerHTML = "Del";

label2.innerHTML = "week 2 :"
delBtn2.innerHTML = "Del2";

label.style.marginRight = "5px";
label2.style.marginRight = "5px";

delBtn.style.margin = "5px";
delBtn2.style.margin = "5px";

body.append(label, delBtn, br, label2, delBtn2);
```

```html
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
const label = document.createElement("label");
label.htmlFor = `cash3`;
label.textContent = `Week 3:`;

// adding style || play with margin
label.style.margin = "1rem";

const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
delBtn.innerText = "Button"

// where ever you can append the newly created elements
document.body.appendChild(label);
document.body.appendChild(delBtn);
```

Comment: Using style.margin will also add space around label, where OP question only wants space between label and button.